# How to getting directions in gmaps4rails v2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmaps4rails

i have researched many sources and could not find any help in getting directions in the v2 of gmaps4rails. i would like to either get directions in a text format (step by step list) or just show the directions on my map it self. I would like my starting point to be a lat and long and the destination also to be a lat and long. thank you any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward [from google example here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple?hl=FR):

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function calcRoute() {
  var origin      = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(42.850033, -85.6500523);
  var request = {
      origin:      origin,
      destination: destination,
      travelMode:  google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

calcRoute(); // call this anywhere you want

var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  directionsDisplay.setMap(handler.getMap());
});
```

Comment: Hi, apneadiving, I have more than one destination. Can you tell me how can I display routes for more than one destination. e.g: I want to display nearest airport, bus stop and railway station for searched location. With above code, I can display route for either airport, or bus stop or railway station. But I want to display route for all of them

Comment: @apneadiving, if possible could you please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354295/rails-gmaps4rails-get-directions-and-show-on-map  .... I would appreciate any help that u could give me! Thanks!